# Reset Password view isn't loading even though the url contains validation key information on ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

First of all, i have check other solutions here too but it doesn't seem to solve my problem.
The problem is, everything is working ok. If a user clicks on "Forget Password" and enters his username. He is sent an email with reset password link. Now if he clicks on the url, he is directed to the url but the resetpassword page isn't being loaded, instead the other condition, which is HttpNotFound() page is being loaded. Seriously need to know what is going wrong with my code.

This is my ForgotPassword action

```
       [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult ForgotPassword(string username)
        {
            string message = "";
            using (MBNSystemEntities db = new MBNSystemEntities())
            {
                var userdetails = db.Users.Where(x => x.UserName == username).FirstOrDefault();
                if (userdetails != null)
                {
                    string validationKey = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Substring(0, 8);
                    string validationPin = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Substring(0, 4);
                    SendMail(userdetails.Email, validationKey, "ResetPassword");

                    UserValidationRequest uvr = new UserValidationRequest();
                    uvr.UserId = userdetails.UserId;
                    uvr.ValidationType = 1;
                    uvr.ValidationExpiryDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
                    uvr.ValidationKey = validationKey;
                    uvr.ValidationPin = validationPin;
                    uvr.ValidationStatus = 0;
                    db.UserValidationRequests.Add(uvr);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    message = "Reset Password link has been sent to your email id.";
                }
                else
                {
                    message = "Account Not Found";
                }
            }
            ViewBag.Message = message;
            return View();  
        }
```

And this is my ResetPassword action

```
                public ActionResult ResetPassword(string validationKey)
        {
            if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(validationKey))
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
          using (MBNSystemEntities db = new MBNSystemEntities())
            {
                var user = db.UserValidationRequests.Where(x => x.ValidationKey == validationKey).FirstOrDefault();
                if (user != null)
                {
                    ResetPasswordModel model = new ResetPasswordModel();
                    model.validationKey = validationKey;
                    return View(model);
                }
                else
                {
                    return HttpNotFound();
                }
            }
        }
```

I checked by putting breakpoint. The validationKey is  passed null in Forgetpassword(string validationkey) instead of the actual validationkey generated in ForgotPassword action.
This is the email Sample:[image]

Comment: `uvr.ValidationKey = validationKey;` this one is the `null` you are saying?

Comment: No sir, uvr.ValidationKey = validationKey is ok. The value is being passed there. The validationKey in ForgotPassword method is being passed null

Comment: or is it `ResetPassword`?

Comment: Im talking about "public ActionResult ResetPassword(string validationKey)" this one

Comment: can you add the sample mail?

Comment: I have updated the sample email, please check sir

Comment: added an answer, sorry for the late reply. if it answered your question, can you mark it as accepted, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your email sent is wrong in terms of passing values

```
localhost:44338/Accounts/ResetPassword?vk={value}
```

it is looking for a parameter named `vk` but it should be `validationKey`

if you can change your `SendEmail` function to add `validationKey` instead of `vk` it will address your problem

or

in your `ResetPassword(string validationKey)` you can change the name to

`ResetPassword(string vk)`